# What is the issue with this YML file

Tags: yaml, github-actions

```
name: Trigger to QA Repo
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - newfeature
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    env:
      TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Step 1 - Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'adopt'
          cache: maven
      - name: run Api
          run: |
            curl -u ":$TOKEN" \
            -X POST \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
            https://api.github.com/repos/xxx/qa_auto/actions/workflows/myworkflow.yml/dispatches \
            -d '{ "ref": "triggerfromserver" }'
```

Getting error following error on line 24 but I don't see any error. can some one help me in this.

Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/workflow_Branch.yml#L24
You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 24

Comment: Have you tried run on YAMLLint? I tried your code it says: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 26 column 14.       Link: http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: @BlueJapan Thanks for giving the link for verifying yaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you indent `run`. Since `name`'s value is not an object (`name` has the value `run Api`), then `run` cannot be a key in the `name` object, hence why you cannot have `run` as a key in `name`.

I believe this is the YAML you want:

```
name: Trigger to QA Repo
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - newfeature
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    env:
      TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Step 1 - Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'adopt'
          cache: maven
      - name: run Api
        run: |
          curl -u ":$TOKEN" \
          -X POST \
          -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
          https://api.github.com/repos/xxx/qa_auto/actions/workflows/myworkflow.yml/dispatches \
          -d '{ "ref": "triggerfromserver" }'
```

This indentation matches the indentation used in the examples [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/quickstart).